# Retrieving External RSS with ionic livereload

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I've tried the following code to retrieve stock data from the Yahoo Finance RSS feed.

```
$http.get(
"http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s="+symbol+"&region=US&lang=en-US"
);
```

This works perfectly fine with `ionic serve` and `ionic emulate` but in the emulator using `ionic emulate -l` I get a `null` error message. I've searched for a solution but i'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Could you try using this code:

'$http({ method: "GET", url: "LINK" }).then(function (resp) {
            console.log(resp.data);
        }, function (err) {
   console.log(err);
  })'

To make sure it's an error and not just the connection

Comment: The connection seems to be working as starting it with livereload turned off seems to work. I've updated the question.